# Message Board with answers selecting from SQL Server database with proper order

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have message board table in SQL Server, and I need to query board entries with replies in specific order. New board entries at the top, but new answers at the bottom of each board entry.

Original data in the table:

```
ID  AnswerToID 
---------------
095 NULL 
096 NULL 
097 NULL 
098 095 
099 NULL 
100 099
101 099 
102 095 
103 NULL 
104 103
```

I need this query result:

```
ID  AnswerToID
-------------------------
103 NULL
104 103  - answer to 103
099 NULL
101 099  - answer to 99
100 099  - answer to 99
097 NULL
096 NULL
095 NULL
102 095  - answer to 95
098 095  - answer to 95
```

Is there any simple SQL query for this?

The result query will be used by Entity Framework, so maybe there is a simpler way (LINQ) than pure SQL.

Comment: Yes there is a very simple SQL construct - `ORDER BY`. You need a field to order by though. The LINQ method is `,OrderBy()` which is usually just converted to an `ORDER BY`

Comment: I hoped to order records by ID and AnswerToID. Like:     BoardMessages.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).ThenBy(o => o.AnswerToID). But then answers are above main board entries.

Comment: You need to add an artificial key to the start of the order by to push those down further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last result entry (096 NULL) seems out of place. Shouln't it be after 097 NULL?

IAC, try something like this:

```
BoardMessages
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.AnswerToId == null ? b.ID : b.AnswerToId)
    .ThenBy(b => b.AnswerToId == null ? 0 : b.AnswerToId);
```

Comment: i've fixed the result (096). Thx, to tired today :/

Answer (score 0):

For a pure SQL solution you could do the following (the ndx column is for display purposes only and can be removed from the production instance)

```
select * ,
 concat(isnull(AnswerID,ID),'.',(9999-isnull(ID,AnswerID))) as ndx
 from board
 order by concat(isnull(AnswerID,ID),'.',(9999-isnull(ID,AnswerID))) desc
```

which produces a result as follows

```
ID      AnswerID        content         ndx
103     (null)          (null)          103.9896
104     103             answer to 103   103.9895
099     (null)          (null)          099.9900
100     099             answer to 99    099.9899
101     099             answer to 99    099.9898
096     (null)          (null)          096.9903
095     (null)          (null)          095.9904
098     095             answer to 95    095.9901
102     095             answer to 95    095.9897
```